# NHibernate MappingByCode Map Cascade options

Tags: c#, nhibernate, dictionary, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I have the following class with a Dictionary :

```
public class Entity1 
{
    public Dictionary<Entity2,Entity3> Targets { get; set; }
}
```

Mapped currently by this code :

```
    Map(x => x.Targets,
        m => m.Key(k => k.Column("Entity1ID")),
        km => km.ManyToMany(mtm => mtm.Column("Entity2ID")),
        vm => vm.ManyToMany(mtm => mtm.Column("Entity3ID")));
```

I am looking for a way to set different cascade option to the KeyMapping, and a different one to the ValueMapping.
But i can find cascade only in the main "Collection Mapping"

I want the key to have Cascade.None - because a different part of the application manages that entity, and the Value to have Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan.

How can i do that with MbC ?

plus - if i set the "CollectionMapping"'s Cascade - to what Entity does it reflect?

I am using the latest Nhibernate on nuget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK Cascading options on Collections only effect the values of the collection. Having `Cascade.All` on the collection:

```
var e2 = new Entity2();
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    session.Save(e2);

    session.Save(new Entity1 { Dictionary = { { e2, new Entity3() } } }); // should work
    session.Save(new Entity1 { Dictionary = { { new Entity2(), new Entity3() } } }); // does not work

    tx.Commit();
}
```

Comment: that didn't answer the question of how to map different cascade for the key, plus i am more concerned about the Delete cascading of the key/value in the map (I can check the default cascading myself, i want to know how to configure it)

Comment: since cascading doesn't affect the key of the map it is basicly `Cascade.None` for the key. It is not possible to set cascading for the key of a collection